# emacs tabs more vim-like

Tags: emacs

I'm currently trying emacs coming from vim. There is only one thing I desperately miss : tabs (in a GUI sense). I know [TabBarMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/TabBarMode) but it doesn't keep the division of windows (with C-x 3 for example) from tab to tab while Vim does it. Is there any plugin for emacs that handle tabs in a more vim-like way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [elscreen](http://www.morishima.net/~naoto/software/elscreen/).

Comment: I had to install the APEL library (http://www.kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~tomo/elisp/APEL/index.en.html) to run it. It almost work as I wanted : keeps the division of windows from tab to tab. However, when I have multiple tabs open and that I split a window, each of the division gets the tab listing over himself, which I don't want.

Comment: You can move the tab listing into the frame title if you want (there's a recipe on the page).  Or fix it yourself, it's just elisp. :)

Comment: I too want the tab listing shown only once, just like in Vim. The APEL page is gone and thus I can't find the "recipe"...

Answer (score 0):

Emacs users know that tabs of all types are [evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabsAreEvil). :-)  This must explain why this particularly useful metaphor has not caught fire among Emacs users.  We're still waiting for a good, easy, implementation of GUI tabs, IMHO.

There is some promising (but young) development work (see [Gtk tabs in emacs, new branch.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/123014)) going on to do GTK tabs in Emacs.  And you'll be happy to know that there is some competent enthusiasm currently at play in the wide new land of distributed Emacs development.  However, even though Emacs development is proceeding at quite a pace (by comparison with recent history, it's breakneck!), it may be a while before GUI tabs 'just work.'

Comment: -1: The page you are linking discusses tabs as indentation (\t). The question is about tabs as a GUI element.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: He was clearly making a joke. +1 for sense of humour :)

Comment: ok. I took my vote back and converted fake hyperlink into the real one as a bonus.